# What would happen if I remove + from the line number 6?

Tags: solidity, ether, payable, payments

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract SendMoneyExample{
    uint public balanceRecived;
    function recivedMoney()public payable{
        balanceRecived+=msg.value;
    }
    function getBalance()public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So now you have something like `a += b`. This is the same as writing `a = a + b`, but just a shorthand version. So you are increasing the value of `a` by the value of `b`.

If you remove `+` sign it simply becomes `a = b`, so you set the value of `a` to be the value of `b`.